# Random Numbers from preset list

Tags: c, arrays, list, random

I'm a student and in the middle of a midterm project. I am not looking for people to code this for me but I need help with part of it. I am trying to make a Blackjack game and to do that I want to set a list of 52 integers [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2.....] one for each card in a deck. But how do take a random number from the list and cancel it out? Just like a normal deck once you take a card you can't redraw it. I know a can set a random parameter [n = rand () % 11 + 1] for the program but I want to go above and beyond to get an A

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to remove a random element from an array.
What you can do instead is to swap the randomly selected element with the last element of the array.  Along with this, you'll need to store the count of **valid**  elements in the array in a variable `array_size_valid`and decrement that value every time the swapping takes place.

This way you're random index generation function will become:

`rand_index = rand () % array_size_valid;`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an trivial way: Say you have an array, containing 52 integers:

```
int deck[52];
```

And you have initialised it to the value you want, such as 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, .....

When a card is drawn, set the corresponding array element to -1 (or any value other than the original ones):

```
int drawCard(int deck[])
{
    do{
        int randIndex = rand () % 52;
    } while(deck[randIndex] == -1);

    int drawnCard = deck[randIndex];
    deck[randIndex] = -1;
    return drawnCard;
}
```

Although this approach may not be efficient enough, it does work, so I think it may be helpful to beginners like you.

Comment: @jojobuddy13 Please accept this answer if you feel it solves your problem :)

Comment: This has the possibility to go into an infinite loop.

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi Yes that's theoretically possible, but this situation won't happen in practice. Modern CPUs can run millions of loops per second.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a shuffling algorithm, like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle. The Fisher - Yates shuffle starts with an array, then it switches every item of the array with a random item from the array. It is also possible to remove items one by one, but it is more complicated. You can remove items one by one randomly using a binary tree. Store the total number of items under each node. Every time, to remove an item, generate a random number a greater than or equal to 0 and less than the number of items left. Start with the root. Go to the left child if a is less than the number of items under the left child. Otherwise, let a be a-, and go to the right child. Do this recursively. But removing items one by one is more complicated. It is better to just use a shuffling algorithm.